# Setting a variable to a GUI label in Python

Tags: python, tkinter

so I have a problem that I need some help fixing in my code. My goal is to have the user input some specific text into a entry box on a GUI in python and then it will output a response (I have chosen to have Chuck Norris and Mr. T comebacks). The problem is that it is not outputting the response (which is the comeback). What I want it to do is output the response onto the GUI. I have tried the .set() syntax but I may have done it wrong.
Here is the code:

```
# IMPORTS #
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import random


# CLASS #
class Comeback:
    def __init__(self, comeback_list):
        self.comeback_list = comeback_list

    def get_random_comeback(self):
        return random.choice(self.comeback_list)


def main():
    mr_t_comebacks = ["Every time a church bell rings, Mr. T pities a fool. ",
                      "The last man who made eye contact with Mr. T was Ray Charles. ",

                      "Mr. T is so scary that his hair is actually afraid to grow. The only reason he has a mohawk is because it's in his blind spot. ",
                      "Google doesn't allow you to search for Mr. T because it knows you don't find Mr. T, he finds you. ",
                      "World champion eater Takeru Kobayashi once ate 53.5 hot dogs in 12 minutes. Allotted the same time, Mr. T ate Kobayashi. ",
                      "Children are afraid of the dark. Dark is afraid of Mr. T. ",
                      "Mr. T stole Michael Jackson's black. ", "5 out of 5 doctors recommend not annoying Mr. T. ",
                      "When Mr. T received his star on Hollywood's Walk of Fame, he made his hand prints after the cement was dry. "]
    chuck_norris_comebacks = ["Chuck Norris counted to infinity... Twice.",
                              "When the Bogeyman goes to sleep at night he checks his closet for Chuck Norris.",
                              "Chuck Norris has already been to Mars; that's why there are no signs of life there.",
                              "Guns don't kill people. Chuck Norris kills People.",
                              "Chuck Norris uses pepper spray to spice up his steaks.",
                              "The Great Wall of China was originally created to keep Chuck Norris out. It failed ",
                              "Chuck Norris can win a game of Connect Four in only three moves.",
                              "Chuck Norris can win a game of chess in only one move... a roundhouse kick to the face."]
    mr_t = Comeback(mr_t_comebacks)
    chuck_norris = Comeback(chuck_norris_comebacks)
    answer = who.get().lower()
    if "mr t" in answer:
        print(mr_t)

    elif "chuck norris" in answer:
        print(chuck_norris)

    elif "give up" in answer:
        print("I win")
        exit()
    else:
        print("Put something relevant in or Chuck Norris will team up with Mr. T and they will come for you")
        main()


# GUI CODE #
root = Tk()
root.title("Chuck Norris vs Mr. T")

# Create the top frame
top_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(root, text="Comebacks")
top_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="NSEW")

# Create and set the message text variable
message_text = StringVar()
message_text.set("Welcome! It's time for some comebacks!")

# Create and pack the message label
message_label = ttk.Label(top_frame, textvariable=message_text, justify="center")
message_label.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

# Create the bottom frame
bottom_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(root, text="User Input")
bottom_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=5, sticky="NSEW")

# Create and set the account details variable
question = StringVar()
question.set("Would you like a Mr. T comeback or a Chuck Norris comeback?")

# Create the details label and pack it into the GUI
details_label = ttk.Label(bottom_frame, textvariable=question, wraplength=300, justify="center")
details_label.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=10, pady=3)

# Create a variable to store the response
who = StringVar()
who.set("")

# Create an entry to type in answer
comeback_entry = ttk.Entry(bottom_frame, textvariable=who)
comeback_entry.grid(row=5, column=1, padx=20, pady=5)

# Create a submit button
submit_button = ttk.Button(bottom_frame, text="Submit", command=main)
submit_button.grid(row=7, column=1, padx=100, pady=5)

#  Create the response variable
comeback_text = StringVar()
comeback_text.set("")

# Create the response label and pack it in the GUI
comeback_label = ttk.Label(top_frame, textvariable=comeback_text)
comeback_label.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=10)

# Run the main function
root.mainloop()
```

Any help would be great, thanks

Comment: You posted way too much code. Please produce the minimal example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem in the `else` block under `main()` because it calls `main()` again and gets stuck in a loop. Take out the `main()` part there.

Another problem: `Comeback.get_random_comeback()` is never called.

And another problem is that you never set `comeback_text`.

With this block it achieves your goal:

```
    mr_t = Comeback(mr_t_comebacks).get_random_comeback()
    chuck_norris = Comeback(chuck_norris_comebacks).get_random_comeback()
    answer = who.get().lower()
    if "mr t" in answer:
        print(mr_t)
        comeback_text.set(mr_t)
    elif "chuck norris" in answer:
        print(chuck_norris)
        comeback_text.set(chuck_norris)
    elif "give up" in answer:
        print("I win")
        exit()
    else:
        print("Put something relevant in or Chuck Norris will team up with Mr. T and they will come for you")
```